# Function that goes through all tuples in a list - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a tuple that consists of a list of tuples where each tuple has a string and a list of strings. I need to write a function that goes through each tuple, and for each tuple it has to check if the input word is in that list.
This is a shortened version of the list:

```
check = [
    ("fruit",["apple", "pear", "banana"]),
    ("berries",["strawberry", "raspberry", "blueberry"]) ]
```

and this is what my desired function should do:

```
convert "apple" = "fruit"
```

Any advice? Should I use a case lookup function or should I use a higher order function such as map? I'm a beginner, so any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: if you're a beginner, code this  with recursion.